# Does a "simple" way to test package on Laravel and Lumen exist?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, lumen

I'm writing a package for Laravel and I also would like it to be compatible with Lumen.
At the moment, I'm using [orchestral/testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) for testing my package, but it was made for Laravel testing, not for Lumen.

I'm looking for a way to be able to test both of them *without changing my composer dependencies* between test runs.

I saw that it is possible to install `laravel/framework: ^7.0` and `laravel/lumen-framework: ^7.0` at the same time so finally created a dummy application with a `bootstrap.laravel.php` and `bootstrap.lumen.php`.

For my tests, I created a bootstrap file for PHPUnit:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as LaravelTestCase;
use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase as LumenTestCase;

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('TEST_MODE=' . env('TEST_MODE', 'laravel'));

$mode = env('TEST_MODE', 'laravel');

if ($mode === 'lumen') {
    class_alias(LumenTestCase::class, 'Sandbox\\TestCase');
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/sandbox/bootstrap/bootstrap.laravel.php';
} else {
    class_alias(LaravelTestCase::class, 'Sandbox\\TestCase');
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/sandbox/bootstrap/bootstrap.lumen.php';
}
```

which allow my tests to extend the `Sandbox\TestCase` which points to the Laravel or Lumen test case depending of the `TEST_MODE` environment variable.

This workaround sounds pretty hacky and I was wondering if there was any standard to do this kind of tests.

Comment: I'm asking this only for my curiosity, Why you would use this package? And why you have two different versions of tests?

Comment: My company has a Lumen project which requires a highly configurable JWT integration. I already wrote the library for Lumen 7 but I would like to share it open-source and also make it compatible with Laravel, since it is more widely used.

Comment: If someone reaches here. Can try mine for lume https://github.com/ssi-anik/testbench-lumen. And orchestral/testbench for laravel.